# Como dar nome a chave estrangeira no Entity framework

Tags: c#

```
public class Lancamento {

     // Colunas e métodos omitidos 

     [Column("IdContaBancaria")]
     public virtual ContaBancaria ContaBancaria { get; set; }
}

public class ContaBancaria
{
        [Key] // PK
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] // Será auto incremento
        [Column("idContaBancaria"]
        public int IdContaBancaria { get; set; }   

        public virtual ICollection<Lancamento> LancamentosCB { get; set; }
       // Colunas e métodos omitidos 
}
```

Gostaria de deixar explicito o nome das fk mas o nome gerado sempre `[ContaBancaria_IdContaBancaria]`

Como definir o nome da chave estrangeira ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o atributo **ForeignKey**:

```
[ForeignKey("fk_nome")]
```